# 条件が一致したとき、合計値を算出する

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**前提・実現したいこと**

その年の売上を月毎に算出してます。
また、会社、販売場所をグループ化しています。

店舗と店舗免税を区別せずに店舗として、合計値を算出したいです。

ご教授の程、宜しくお願い申し上げます。

**補足情報**

MySQL 5.7

**現在の状態**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**該当のソースコード**

```
SELECT 
    CASE  
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 AND `point_of_sale_id`=2) THEN 'F  社 - 店舗' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 AND `point_of_sale_id`=3) THEN 'F  社 - 店舗免税'
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 AND `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN 'F  社 - 国内通販' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 AND `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN 'F  社 - 海外通販' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2)                          THEN 'F  社 - 合計' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 3 AND `point_of_sale_id`=2) THEN 'R  社 - 店舗' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 3 AND `point_of_sale_id`=3) THEN 'R  社 - 店舗免税' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 3 AND `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN 'R  社 - 国内通販' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 3 AND `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN 'R  社 - 海外通販' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 3)                          THEN 'R  社 - 合計' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 4 AND `point_of_sale_id`=2) THEN 'C  社 - 店舗' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 4 AND `point_of_sale_id`=3) THEN 'C  社 - 店舗免税' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 4 AND `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN 'C  社 - 国内通販' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 4 AND `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN 'C  社 - 海外通販'  
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 4)                          THEN 'C  社 - 合計' 
    END AS '発注元の会社 - 販売した場所' 
    ,sum.`1月`
    ,sum.`2月`
    ,sum.`3月`
    ,sum.`4月`
    ,sum.`5月`
    ,sum.`6月`
    ,sum.`7月`
    ,sum.`8月`
    ,sum.`9月`
    ,sum.`10月`
    ,sum.`11月`
    ,sum.`12月`
FROM (
    SELECT 
         `orderer_id`
        ,`point_of_sale_id`
        ,SUM(
            IF(
                EXTRACT(MONTH from `payment_confirm`) = '01'
                , CASE 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=2 OR `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN `usually_grand_total` + `grand_consumption_tax_total` 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=3 OR `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN `custom_grand_total` 
                END
            , 0)
        ) AS '1月' 
        ,SUM(
            IF(
                EXTRACT(MONTH from `payment_confirm`) = '02'
                , CASE 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=2 OR `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN `usually_grand_total` + `grand_consumption_tax_total` 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=3 OR `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN `custom_grand_total` 
                END
            , 0)
        ) AS '2月' 
        ,SUM(
            IF(
                EXTRACT(MONTH from `payment_confirm`) = '03'
                , CASE 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=2 OR `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN `usually_grand_total` + `grand_consumption_tax_total` 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=3 OR `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN `custom_grand_total` 
                END
            , 0)
        ) AS '3月' 
        ,SUM(
            IF(
                EXTRACT(MONTH from `payment_confirm`) = '04'
                , CASE 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=2 OR `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN `usually_grand_total` + `grand_consumption_tax_total` 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=3 OR `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN `custom_grand_total` 
                END
            , 0)
        ) AS '4月' 
        ,SUM(
            IF(
                EXTRACT(MONTH from `payment_confirm`) = '05'
                , CASE 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=2 OR `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN `usually_grand_total` + `grand_consumption_tax_total` 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=3 OR `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN `custom_grand_total` 
                END
            , 0)
        ) AS '5月' 
        ,SUM(
            IF(
                EXTRACT(MONTH from `payment_confirm`) = '06'
                , CASE
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=2 OR `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN `usually_grand_total` + `grand_consumption_tax_total` 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=3 OR `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN `custom_grand_total` 
                END
            , 0)
        ) AS '6月' 
        ,SUM(
            IF(
                EXTRACT(MONTH from `payment_confirm`) = '07'
                , CASE 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=2 OR `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN `usually_grand_total` + `grand_consumption_tax_total` 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=3 OR `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN `custom_grand_total` 
                END
            , 0)
        ) AS '7月' 
        ,SUM(
            IF(
                EXTRACT(MONTH from `payment_confirm`) = '08'
                , CASE 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=2 OR `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN `usually_grand_total` + `grand_consumption_tax_total` 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=3 OR `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN `custom_grand_total` 
                END
            , 0)
        ) AS '8月' 
        ,SUM(
            IF(
                EXTRACT(MONTH from `payment_confirm`) = '09'
                , CASE 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=2 OR `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN `usually_grand_total` + `grand_consumption_tax_total` 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=3 OR `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN `custom_grand_total` 
                END
            , 0)
        ) AS '9月' 
        ,SUM(
            IF(
                EXTRACT(MONTH from `payment_confirm`) = '10'
                , CASE 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=2 OR `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN `usually_grand_total` + `grand_consumption_tax_total` 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=3 OR `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN `custom_grand_total` 
                END
            , 0)
        ) AS '10月' 
        ,SUM(
            IF(
                EXTRACT(MONTH from `payment_confirm`) = '11'
                , CASE 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=2 OR `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN `usually_grand_total` + `grand_consumption_tax_total` 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=3 OR `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN `custom_grand_total` 
                END
            , 0)
        ) AS '11月' 
        ,SUM(
            IF(
                EXTRACT(MONTH from `payment_confirm`) = '12'
                , CASE 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=2 OR `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN `usually_grand_total` + `grand_consumption_tax_total` 
                    WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 OR `orderer_id`= 3 OR `orderer_id`= 4) AND (`point_of_sale_id`=3 OR `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN `custom_grand_total` 
                END
            , 0)
        ) AS '12月' 
    FROM 
        vw_sales_budget 
    WHERE 
        EXTRACT(YEAR from `payment_confirm`) = '2017' 
    AND 
        `orderer_id` NOT IN(1) 
    AND 
        `point_of_sale_id` NOT IN(1) 
    GROUP BY 
         orderer_id
        ,point_of_sale_id
    WITH ROLLUP 
) AS sum;
```

**ビュー**

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `hironobu`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `vw_sales_budget` AS
    SELECT 
        `ps`.`process_status_id` AS `process_status_id`,
        `so`.`orderer_id` AS `orderer_id`,
        `pos`.`point_of_sale_id` AS `point_of_sale_id`,
        `so`.`usually_grand_total` AS `usually_grand_total`,
        `so`.`custom_grand_total` AS `custom_grand_total`,
        `so`.`grand_consumption_tax_total` AS `grand_consumption_tax_total`,
        `so`.`payment_confirm` AS `payment_confirm`
    FROM
        (((`sales_order` `so`
        JOIN `processes_status` `ps` ON ((`so`.`processing_status_id` = `ps`.`process_status_id`)))
        JOIN `companys` `cp` ON ((`so`.`orderer_id` = `cp`.`company_id`)))
        JOIN `point_of_sales` `pos` ON ((`so`.`point_of_sale_id` = `pos`.`point_of_sale_id`)))
    WHERE
        (`so`.`processing_status_id` <> 8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のようなSQLで実現できると思います

```
SELECT
    CASE
        -- mysql は 集約関数外で 集約対象カラム を利用すると 値が1つランダムに手に入る
        -- (だいたい先頭の値、保証はなく実装依存)
        -- なので、店舗 + 店舗免税 の集約をしたカラムの point_of_sale_id は [2, 3] のどちらか
        -- キチンとする(PostgreSQLとかでも動くようにする)なら
        -- MAX(point_of_sale_id) AS point_of_sale_id_agg
        -- のようにする
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 AND `point_of_sale_id`=2) OR
             (`orderer_id`= 2 AND `point_of_sale_id`=3) THEN 'F  社 - 店舗 + 店舗免税' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 AND `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN 'F  社 - 国内通販' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2 AND `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN 'F  社 - 海外通販' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 2)                          THEN 'F  社 - 合計' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 3 AND `point_of_sale_id`=2) OR
             (`orderer_id`= 3 AND `point_of_sale_id`=3) THEN 'R  社 - 店舗 + 店舗免税' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 3 AND `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN 'R  社 - 国内通販' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 3 AND `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN 'R  社 - 海外通販' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 3)                          THEN 'R  社 - 合計' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 4 AND `point_of_sale_id`=2) OR
             (`orderer_id`= 4 AND `point_of_sale_id`=3) THEN 'C  社 - 店舗 + 店舗免税' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 4 AND `point_of_sale_id`=4) THEN 'C  社 - 国内通販' 
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 4 AND `point_of_sale_id`=5) THEN 'C  社 - 海外通販'  
        WHEN (`orderer_id`= 4)                          THEN 'C  社 - 合計' 
    END AS '発注元の会社 - 販売した場所' 
    ,SUM(sum.`1月`)
    -- ...
    ,SUM(sum.`12月`)
FROM (
    -- ...
) AS sum
GROUP BY
  `orderer_id`,
  CASE point_of_sale_id
  WHEN 2 THEN 2 -- 店舗(店舗免税と同じ値)
  WHEN 3 THEN 2 -- 店舗免税(店舗と同じ値)
         ELSE point_of_sale_id -- それ以外
  END
;
```